# Is Ubuntu touch available on the Meizu MX6 android version?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

First of all i want to say i am new to this website. I tried to look for answers before posting this question. Because i could not find it i will ask it here. Is it easy to put ubuntu touch on the meizu MX6? I ask this because there is an ubuntu version of the X6! Is this easy or it would be better to wait for the release of the MX6 ubuntu touch version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find supported device here:
https://devices.ubports.com/#/
And the official devices on the ubuntu touch site.
For now the project is a bit slow down becose they are putting their efforts in moving .click to snap .. 
Anyway i won't try .. I never heard about ubuntu touch on mx6 and the flash could brick your phone.
Follow the mailinglist...

Comment: In that case i think i have to wait for the MX6 ubuntu version release. To bad because i have no idea if there will be ubuntu version for sure. But thank you anyway!

Comment: I am sorry but also for the leaders of the project at this moment is difficult to say what future's commercial plans has canonical for the phones.. Maybe there are not at all.